# Is it possible to load electron webContents from an in memory html string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Let's say I've got 2 processes:

Process 1 is sending to process 2 a valid html string:

```
ipcRenderer.send('open-window-from-string', 
'<!DOCTYPE html>' + '<html>' + htmlElement.innerHTML + '</html>');
```

Process 2 (Electron Main-Process) is trying to open a new window from that string:

```
ipc.on('open-window-from-string', (event, htmlString) => {
  const windowFromString= BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(htmlString);
}
```

I know I could save the html as an actual html file. That way everything worked while using:

```
loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/windowFromString.html`);
```

However that would cause unnecessary read/write actions.

That's why I am trying to load a new window from a htmlString out of my memory.
So again the question is: 
**Is it possible to load electron webContents from an in memory html string?**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,
Megajin

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in Chrome, you can display inline html pages by navigating URL with data: protocol such as `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> <title>MyYTitle</title> <style type="text/css"> </style></head> <body>Hello world from Lyon, FR</body>`

It works the same in Electron.
Can you try opening a window with `loadURL('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<YOUR HTML/>');`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this is fortunately a working option if you do not use any JavaScript inside of the HTML. That's why I'm going to accept [devilpreet's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44838469/4457744) answer. However if someone is going to build a kind of WebScraper which will ignore JavaScript anyway this is the preferred solution +1 for you.

Comment: `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<body>Hello world from Lyon, FR<script>alert(1)</script></body>` shows the `alert` in Chrome

Comment: is working. Changed your answer to be the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, perhaps you cannot directly load whole html. As a workaround, you can open a new browser window with just contents as:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

After you open this you can use browserWindow.webContents.evaluate() to load actual HTML passed as String. If required you can use webContents.reload() for changes to take effect.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, unfortunately this is the only way to make the JavaScript work too on the given HTML... However as long as one is not using any precompiling stuff beforehand your solution is the only option left. One should consider using `loadURL('data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<YOUR HTML/>');` from [sritmak's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44828510/4457744) answer and your `webContents.reload();`